# Comparing a date with a list of dates

Tags: javascript, date, compare, xpages

I have a view listing holiday dates. And I have a date field on my form which needs to be different from my holiday date list. So I've created a validator to check it.

```
<xp:validateExpression message="İzin başlangıcı resmi tatillere denk gelemez.">
    <xp:this.expression>
        <![CDATA[#{javascript:var dHolidays = @DbColumn(@DbName(),"(lookupHoliday)", 1);
            !@IsMember(value, dHolidays)}]]>
    </xp:this.expression>
</xp:validateExpression>
```

This would work great on formula language but xpages has some wacky date format and I can't compare.

Comment: I've solved my problem by serializing the date in the view and comparing as string. This works well but I'd like to know if theres a proper and practical way to do it.

    var dHolidays = @DbColumn(@DbName(),"(lookupHolidaySerialized)", 1);
    
    sValue = @Right(@Text(100+@Day(value)),2) + "." + @Right(@Text(100+@Month(value)),2) + "." + @Text(@Year(value));
    !@IsMember(sValue, dHolidays)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` to convert date values to string and to compare them in validateExpression:

```
    var sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    var dHolidays = @DbColumn(@DbName(),"(lookupHoliday)", 1);
    var newDate = sdf.format(value);
    for (var i=0; i < dHolidays.length; i++) {
        if (sdf.format(dHolidays[i]) === newDate) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
```

You can list normal Notes dates (not strings) in your view's first column this way.

Comment: Preformatting the date is a good practice. It'll help me a lot.